# Interchangeability of motorcycle parts

Tags: motorcycle, parts

How standardized are motorcycle parts? Is every manufacturer doing their own thing or could you take parts such as a crankshaft from a Honda machine and use them in a Yamaha machine?

Are there manufacturers who care for this issue and try to use as many generic parts as possible in their machines so that you can use parts across models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Motorcycle parts aren't very standardized across manufacturers**

I think going so far as to make crankshafts interchangeable isn't a sign that a manufacturer cares about standardization though.  A crankshaft is a central component of an engine and can drive rider feel, power delivery and performance of the vehicle.

There are some manufacturers that are very good about standardizing internally though.  Suzuki has been a great example.  Rectifiers, various switches, front ends, controls and even some engine components can be very interchangeable across models.

Most manufacturers and are not as thoughtful though.

**Cross Brand Standardization**

The simple answer, it doesn't exist.  Other than brake mounts, calipers, sprockets, chains and headlights there really isn't much of this.  I don't see this as an indictment though.  From my perspective the car industry is about the same.